# Not Getting Full URL in own custom template in odoo?

Tags: email, url, odoo-12

I am new to odoo and I am trying to get full URL in my own custom template. Please check my code and help to sort it out what I am doing wrong.

**mail_template_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<data noupdate = "0">
    <record id="example_email_template" model="mail.template">
      <field name="name">Example e-mail template</field>
      <field name="email_from">bhuwankhadka2052@greenit.com.np</field>
      <field name="subject">Congratz khadka</field>
      <field name="email_to">benkhadka143@gmail.com</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_tender_manage"/>
      <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
      <field name="body_html">
          <![CDATA[
            <p>Dear ,<br/><br/>

            Good job, you've just created your first e-mail template!<br/></p>
                My name is Bhuwan Khadka. What about you man?
               A new tender record has been created

                <div>
                <p>Please check the link below for more details:</p>  

                    % set website_url = object.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('web.base.url')
                    Your Odoo domain is: <b><a href="${website_url}">${website_url}</a></b><br>

                </div>

                Regards,<br/>
                Bhuwan Khadka
          ]]>
      </field>
   </record> 
</data>
```

**tendermanage.py**

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    res = super(TenderManage,self).create(vals)
    self.task_send_mail()
    return res
```

Above code create new record and trigger automate email function

```
@api.multi
def task_send_mail(self):
    template_email = self.env["mail.template"].search([('name','=','Example e-mail template')]).id
    self.env["mail.template"].browse(template_email).sudo().send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

Above code send email

If I remove URL code from XML file, email is sent automatically without any error but when URL code is written in email-template I get following error.

Error Message:

[image]

Please help me with your suggestion and how to get full url in email template. In XML odoo element is removed as it is not shown in above code.

Comment: Thank you @htshame for edit. I was having a problem with how to show the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mail_template_view.xml

```
<div>
   <p>Please check the link below for more details:
      Your Odoo domain is: <b><a href="${object.get_full_url()}">Click Here</a></p>
</div>
```

tendermanage.py

```
@api.multi
def get_full_url(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    base_url = self.env["ir.config_parameter"].get_param("web.base.url")
    url_params = {
        'id': self.id,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'model': 'your_model',
        'menu_id': self.env.ref('module_name.menu_record_id').id,
        'action': self.env.ref('module_name.action_record_id').id,
    }
    params = '/web?#%s' % url_encode(url_params)
    return base_url + params
```

Change the mail template div and create method like this in your model..
i hope it will helps..

Comment: I am still facing same problem. I am confused here, menu_record_id means parent menuitem id or tree id and action_record_id means action menu id or record id.

Comment: menu_id it means your tender_manage <menuitem id="menu_tender_manage"/> like this id..
and action id it means <record id="action_id"  model="ir.actions.act_window"> id..

Comment: This code still working on Odoo14,

If someone got **url_encode** error, maybe you should import werkzeug first,

`import werkzeug.urls` at above. And then on the `params = '/web?#%s' % url_encode(url_params)` update it be like this `params = '/web?#%s' % werkzeug.url_encode(url_params)`

Thanks,
Tri Nanda